# Undo Feature - Enchantments while dead

Tags: league-of-legends

I accidently bought homeguards (instinctively) instead of distortion in a match yesterday (while dead) and it still wouldn't let me undo.

- Is this a bug? I don't see how an enchantment could affect my the game if I'm dead. (And yes I tried to undo before I respawned).
- Has Riot said anything in regards to using undo feature on enchantments (dead or alive; Preferably dead though. I can't seem to find anything official).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is no bug. It could be abused (homeguard in particular) by simply buying the Item, gaining the benficial effect from it (Movementspeed) and then undoing the purchase again with the buff still being on the player.

There is no official statement from Riot but it's a widely accepted community Theory. So always buy the right Boot enchantment.

Answer (score 1):

You can undo enchantments as long as their passives aren't activated OR you're alive.

For example if you buy the homeguard one, you'll instantly be unable to undo that. But if you buy distortion you can.